# How possibly could ISP push information to my browser at any webpage?

Tags: networking, html, isp

While I'm surfing the internet my ISP (internet service provider) manipulate the HTML webpage I'm seeing to push my usage information.

how that is even possible ?

- that happen even if I'm opening a local website from my own visual studio
  or from external website.
- I'm using Orange network at Egypt.
  [image]

Comment: I'm not sure how your ISP is going about things, but for an idea; check out [Deep Packet Inspection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_packet_inspection). Specifically take a look at the section [Deep Packet Inspection with ISPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_packet_inspection#DPI_at_network.2FInternet_service_providers).

Comment: It's their DNS service most likely... in some cases you can get around it by setting static DNS servers like 8.8.8.8/8.8.4.4 but it depends on how they are "stealing" the DNS lookups. Otherwise you only have 2 choices, use a privacy VPN or switch ISP's.

Comment: @acejavelin DNS alone can't insert anything in the web-pages themselves. There is more going on here.

Comment: @Tonny No, but there have been a few questions recently where the user has had common DNS entries for things like common ads hijacked at the ISP DNS server level, redirecting them to ISP hosted ads, which makes it appear like they are "inserting" it into a web page.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways how this can be done. They can even be used in combination.

1. Your ISP uses a "transparent proxy": Basically all HTTP traffic is intercepted at their end and run through a proxy server and (if they want to do that,) they can manipulate it however they want before they send it to your computer. Very common with data-bundles on cell-phones. There are legitimate reasons for such proxies to be used (like caching frequently requested webpages), but modifying the traffic is in my view not one of them.
2. Your ISP tells you to use a regular proxy: Set in the proxy-settings of your web-browser. Look there and switch it of. If you can use the internet without that setting you get probably rid of the messages, but be warned: It is possible your usage counter is going up quicker than without using the proxy so you hit the data-cap quicker. (Traffic going through the proxy is usually partially "free of charge".)
3. Deep Packet Inspection: It is exactly like 1) but works at a deeper level of the network. This allows the ISP to even detect web-traffic if it is happening on non-standard port-numbers (E.g. anything other than port 80.) Like 1) the technology has it's uses, but again: It shouldn't be used for something like this.
4. Some ISP's provide an mandatory or optional software package to install on your computer in order to use their services. This software could be adding the popup too. I've seen a couple of ISP's that provided a "free" anti-virus program to their customers. They didn't tell that this software also monitored your usage and reported that to the ISP.

There are probably several other way how to do this. Those 4 are just the most common I can think of right now.

In my view an ISP should never do this. By modifying http traffic like this they can seriously mess up some web-sites, making them unusable to their customers.

The only way around this is using a VPN or Tor. There is no way they can intercept that. (In case of 4) the locally installed software may even be able to mess with that.)